# How to perform Range Search on 3D points set with CGAL?

Tags: c++, search, geometry, range, cgal

So I saw this nice [2D Range and Neighbor Search](http://www.cgal.org/Manual/latest/doc_html/cgal_manual/Point_set_2/Chapter_main.html) I alsow saw [dD Range and Segment Trees](http://www.cgal.org/Manual/latest/doc_html/cgal_manual/SearchStructures/Chapter_main.html)  yet I can not understand how to perform a 3D Range and Neighbor Search on a 3D point set. Generaly I want to query some points container for an array of points that are in distance `R` from some given point `P`. (Remark: why I do not want to do it manually - such search can be CPU/GPU/SSE optimized and I would like to use tested reliable *efficient* library in favour of my own)

Answer (score 2):

The example [Example for Range Tree on Set-like Data](http://www.cgal.org/Manual/latest/doc_html/cgal_manual/SearchStructures/Chapter_main.html#Subsection_62.5.2) is the example for the 2D-case. Turn the _2 into _3 in the typedefs and you have the 3D case.